# Custom Control Component Implementing ControlValueAccessor and Validator Not Staying In Sync With Consuming FormGroup

Tags: angular, formgroups, controlvalueaccessor, angular-abstract-control

**Background:**

I have a custom email control component (`EmailControlComponent`) that implements `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator`. The `validate()` method of `EmailControlComponent` accepts a single `AbstractControl` parameter. Per Angular's API, the validate method is called each time the consuming parent FormGroup emits valueChanges on the customer email control.

**Example:**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-control-using-controlvalueaccessor?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**The Question:**

Why is the `validate()` method's `AbstractControl` parameter out of sync with the parent FormGroup's status?

If you take a look at the demo above and view the console, you should see that the logged `control.status` is always `VALID`, regardless of the controls actual status. The parent FormGroup correctly shows the control's status toggling between `VALID` and `INVALID` appropriately, but the `validate()` parameter status never changes.

What am I doing wrong?

**References:**

https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALIDATORS

Answer (score 0):

When you have a custom form control that implements validator you can add a function `validate`. This function validate it's a function that return, **based in the value of the control**, null or an object.

But this custom form control can be feed with a FormControl that have Validators. (This is the aims to write in provider:  `multi: true,`)

I want to say that your function validate should be, e.g.

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const EMAIL_REGEXP =
    /^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value) ? null : {'email': true};
}
```

And when you create the FormControl only write

```
  email=new FormControl('',Validators.required)
```

Or not implement validator

Has no sense to have a validate function that only ask about control.valid

**Update** if we can "check" in the custom formControl if the formControl has external validators and it's fullfilled or not we can access to the function validator

Some like

```
validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  const error=control && control.validator?
          control.validator(new FormControl(control.value)):
          null

  //in error we have the errors: the inner and the outer error

  ..rest of our code...
}
```

See that you can access to the "validator function" of the control. The only is feed with a new formControl with the same value than the control.value

So, the before code give us in error an object with the errors. Be careful, has the errors from outer and the inner error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that my example is a little contrived. I moved the `Validators.email` to the email-control.component.ts. The underlying question still applies though. Why is the AbstractControl value that is passed to the validate method not in sync with the consuming parent? Thanks!

Comment: For example, if in that validate method we wanted to take into consideration both the local validation as well as any layered validation the consuming parent applied, we don't have visibility to that. e.g. `return (this.email.valid && control.valid) ? null : {invalidEmail: true};`

Comment: @Joe, you can use some like:`const error=control && control.validator?control.validator(new FormControl(control.value)):null`, see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Saw this on reddit and came here, so in short your custom email control doesn't need a formControl in it, you already have the formControl from the parent.  You are extending the ControlValueAccessor, so you should/could have:
`@Optional() @Self() protected override controlDir: NgControl` in your constructor and then assign it to itself `controlDir.valueAccessor = this;`

I'll try and find an example and update this post.

Comment: Awesome! I'm looking forward to the example. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention. Feel free to fork my StackBlitz and adjust it for your example. Thanks!